# Is there a control like MediaPlayerElement, but without the video part?

Tags: uwp

Is there any UI control that is like the MediaPlayerElement, but for audio only? Or is there any way I can remove the video section of the MediaPlayerElement? I'm building a media player but only for audio, so I don't need the video section, that takes too much space.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I've never used UWP specifically)

Use the `MediaPlayerElement` but give it an explicit height so that the video/poster-frame area collapses (assuming you're using the default `Stretch="Uniform"` or `Stetch="UniformToFill"`).

Answer (score 0):

`MediaPlayerElement` is not dedicated to playing video, it can also play audio. It is just a control that carries media.

You only need to provide an audio source. When the video source is not input, `MediaPlayerElement` will not display the video area.

**Xaml**

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MediaContainer" Height="100">
    <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="MyPlayer"
                    AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                    AutoPlay="True"
                    >
        <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
            <MediaTransportControls ShowAndHideAutomatically="False"
                                             x:Name="MyPlayerControls"
                                             IsZoomButtonVisible="False"
                                             IsFullWindowButtonVisible="False"
                                             IsFastRewindButtonVisible="True"
                                             IsFastForwardEnabled="True"
                                             IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True"
                                             IsFastRewindEnabled="True"
                                             />
        </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
    </MediaPlayerElement>
</Grid>
```

**Xaml.cs**

```cs
private MediaSource _mediaSource = null;
private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer = null;

public void InitMedia(string audioUri)
{
    if (_mediaPlayer == null)
    {
        _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        MyPlayer.SetMediaPlayer(_mediaPlayer);
    }
    _mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(audioUri));
    _mediaPlayer.Source = _mediaSource;
}
```

`MediaPlayer` itself is a player without UI. `MediaPlayerElement` provides `MediaTransportControls` to control the playback progress. If you don't need this integrated control panel, you can also build your own playback experience around `MediaPlayer`.